# Problems while using a callback function in PHP

Tags: php, callback

I am having this problem When using callback functions

```
Class My_Class {

     public function my_function() {

            $pad = function($value) {
            return str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            };

            function pad_function($value) {
                 return str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            }

            array_map($pad, range(0,100)); //This fails with an exception "Invalid opcode 153/1/8."
            array_map("pad_function", range(0,100)); //This works ok
        }



}
```

I am using PHP version 5.3.3-7.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `$pad` defined?

Comment: there's a blatant syntax error...

Comment: Fix the syntax error first please.

Comment: The "invalid opcode" error looks like a bug in PHP. PHP 5.3.3 is rather outdated; try upgrading to 5.3.16 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I just fixed the syntax error, i tried to rush it too much. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was with eaccelerator.

Version 1.0-dev of eaccelerator carashes when executing the code.
Version 0.9.6.1 of eaccelerator does not crash with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Typos apart, `$pad` is never defined.

Then `array_map` won't call your `$my_pad_function` lambda function, because you passed the `my_pad_function` string as first parameter, telling PHP to look for a function *named* `my_pad_function`: that's different from calling a lambda stored in `$my_pad_function`.

Anyway I advice you not to call everything "my_function", "myPrettyFunction", "myPointlessNameVar": give meaningful names even in playground code, your goal will be clearer.

One last thing:

```
lambdas : PHP = lipstick : pig
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices, the reason for calling them My_Whatever is because i didn't want to just copy & paste my own code (as it contains more vars and so on), that is also the reason why there were so many errors :).