# Invalid opcode 153/1/8 when using anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function, opcode, eaccelerator

My host suddenly changed something , and now my sites ( most wp - around 100 ) are getting the infamous error `Invalid opcode 153/1/8`

The line(s) responsible for it :

```
$f = function() use ($out) {
    echo $out;
};
```

After 2 minutes of research it appears that the culprit is eAccelerator , which [does not support anonymous functions](https://github.com/eaccelerator/eaccelerator/issues/16)

Both the following questions blamed the error on eAccelerator as well :

[Invalide OpCode and php sort function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841026/invalide-opcode-and-php-sort-function),

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12085901/1244126

Fun fact : the same code was already before a subject of my own 2 questions  [here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413627/php-how-to-avoid-parse-errors-on-older-servers-when-using-new-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401270/php-understanding-create-function-passing-simple-variable)  , where I encountered a problem while using 
anonymous functions with older PHP versions ( < 5.3 ) with `create_function`

```
$f = create_function(' $out ',' global $out; echo $out;');
```

*So, my question is* : how can I change my code in a manner that will avoid the eAccelerator bug AND will work on all php versions . ( it is unlikely that I can convince my host to change something on it´s side )

**EDIT I :**

For sake of clarity ( although might be slightly irrelevant - the the question is how to have a cross-compatible anonymous functions ) - I am posting the whole relevant code ...

```
    if ( count( $content_widget ) > 0 ) { // avoid error when no widget...
    $i=0;
    foreach ( $content_widget as $wid ){
        $out = null;
        $i++;

        $widg_id = 'o99_dashboard_widget_dyn_' . $i;
        $widg_name = 'widget name  - ' . $i;

        $out = $wid;

        // $f = create_function('$out','global $out;echo $out;'); 
        // $f = create_function('', 'global $out; echo $out ;'); 
        $f = function() use ($out) { 
            echo $out;
        };

        // function() use ($out) // NOPE
        // $f = $f($out); // NOPE again
        wp_add_dashboard_widget($widg_id, $widg_name, $f);
        // $i++;
     }

}
```

It is just a simple code to dynamically create dashboard widgets in wp admin area..

Comment: How do you use this function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they are using [call_user_func](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L869)

So, you could create new object and pass callable array.

```
class s {
    private $_out = null;
    public function __construct($out){
        $this->_out = $out;
    }
    public function a(){
        echo $this->_out;
    }
}

$function = array(new S('my out'), 'a');

var_dump(is_callable($function));

call_user_func($function);
```